# Custom AuthenticationFailureHandler @Bean vs new FailureHandler()

Tags: spring, security

I am implementing my AuthenticationFailureHandler and I am adding it to the filter. Which is the better way to do it and what is the difference:

```
public AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception{
    final AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter  = new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
    authenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/login");
    authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new FailureHandler());
    return authenticationFilter ;
}
```

vs

```
public AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception{
    final AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter  = new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
    authenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/login");
    authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler());
    return authenticationFilter ;
}
@Bean
public AuthenticationFailureHandler customAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
    return new FailureHandler();
}
```

I saw a configuration where they did it with a bean, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Both way are doing the same thing. The only difference is that in the second one you are declaring this FailureHandler as a bean, and if you want(not recommended) you can get it via @autowired in any bean managed by spring.

I prefer the first one, because you are ensuring that the FailureHandler is only on the AuthenticationFilter that you declared.

The second one is used when you don`t need to explict declare the AuthenticationFilter, and you will use one pre-configured by spring.